# Gerah as a coin and cud (and more)

Tags: sources-mekorot, words

Is anyone familiar with any exposition on the connection between gerah גֵּרָה as cud (ma'aleh gerah) and as a measure of 1/20th of a shekel? Is there any connection drawn to the root for the word תִּתְגָּר as in Dev 2:19, provoke (which the Even Shoshan connects to the same 3 letter root)?

I am not looking specifically for an etymological link, though that would be interesting, but a homiletic one also.

Comment: The "גרה" coin's root is "גרה", while the root of "גרה" from "מעלה גרה" is "גרר". There [might be](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/kitveyet/taleley/gerot-2.htm) a connection between "גרה" (from "תתגר") and "גרר" (from "מעלה גרה"), and the idea of a "convert" (גר).

Comment: Gerah was originally a weight, so perhaps the average cud weighed around a gerah?